# Nosegae Unit Tests with gae-session on a Python Google App Engine Project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, webtest, nosetests

I can't get [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki) to work when I use unit tests. I'm not sure if it's a cookie issue or an internal gae-sessions issue (it uses memcache/the datastore for persistance). It works fine on the actual app when accessed through a browser.

I'm using Python 2.5 on Mac OS 10.6.6, Google App Engine SDK 1.4.2, nosetests version 1.0.0, NoseGAE-0.1.7 and gae-sessions v1.06.

Here's my code:

---

web app implementation:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from gaesessions import get_current_session

class cookietest(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        s = get_current_session()
        if not 'message' in s:
            self.response.out.write('No session value')
            s['message'] = 'This value is stored in a session'
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Message found: %s" % s['message'])

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/cookietest', cookietest)])
```

---

Unit test implementation:

```
def test_cookietest(self):
    from gaesessions import SessionMiddleware
    app_with_sessions = SessionMiddleware(application, cookie_key=os.urandom(64)) # random key
    self.app = TestApp(app_with_sessions)

    resp = self.app.get('/cookietest')
    cookie = resp.headers['Set-Cookie']
    assert cookie
    resp = self.app.get('/cookietest', headers={'Cookie': cookie})
    print resp
    assert 'This value is stored in a session' in resp
```

---

The relevant output is:

```
FAIL: test_cookietest (tests.test.TestUser)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Asad/.../test.py", line 33, in test_cookietest
    assert 'This value is stored in a session' in resp
AssertionError: 
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
Response: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie:  DgU00="DQjpTdhQsKYYGhvNr/CLm+v835QV5V1jTX9T4wMULhI=1301034363_89b1c1007a6159e85828ab9a7673759cgAJ9cQB9cQFVB21lc3NhZ2VxAlUhVGhpcyB2YWx1ZSBpcyBzdG9yZWQgaW4gYSBzZXNzaW9ucQNzhnEELg=="; expires=Fri, 25-Mar-2011 06:26:03 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
No session value

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
root: WARNING: Could not read datastore data from /var/folders/pt/ptPaW5O7E-eLIrfFhhczbU+++TI/-Tmp-/nosegae.datastore
root: INFO: zipimporter('/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/NoseGAE-0.1.7-py2.5.egg', '')
root: INFO: zipimporter('/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/WebTest-1.2.3-py2.5.egg', '')
root: INFO: zipimporter('/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/WebOb-1.0-py2.5.egg', '')
root: INFO: zipimporter('/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/mock-0.7.0b4-py2.5.egg', '')
root: DEBUG: Could not import "strop": Disallowed C-extension or built-in module
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.284s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have to manually save the session in this test.

```
   if not 'message' in s:
        self.response.out.write('No session value')
        s['message'] = 'This value is stored in a session'
        s.save()
```

Update:

[gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki) retrieves the session cookie from the `os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']` variable. This value needs to be set before the `self.app.get` request instead of passing in the cookie in the `headers` parameter.

Comment: Gae-sessions retrieves the cookie from the `os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']` variable.  I don't think passing in the `Cookie` header is equivalent to setting this value.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I just set os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'] before my self.app.get() request and it works just fine. Wanna edit the answer or write another one so I can accept it?